# How to start mysql server in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, mysql

I have problems after updating ubuntu from 11.10 to 12.04 with mysql - before upgrade everything worked fine after upgrade - mysql cannot start mysql server properly. Any ideas? This is my error message:

```
SQL Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

Also where can I enable errors from mysql? I did not find it anywhere. Thank you all.

When I do:

```
ps -ef |grep mysql
```

It shows me this:

```
root      6849  5758  0 00:44 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

Comment: tail -f /var/log/syslog  then try to start mysql. That should give you the reason.

Comment: http://paste2.org/p/2044417 more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply looks like your server isn't running and you are trying to connect to the server before starting it first. It might be that your init scripts are somehow messed up. What command are you using to start the server manually, if you have tried this at all?

1. Try `service mysql start` from a root terminal
2. The error log is at `/var/log/mysql/error.log`. cat it and see if you find anything useful.

Comment: Here are my errors with commands I used http://paste2.org/p/2044417

Comment: In your my.cnf file, try commenting out `default-storage-engine=innodb` and see if you can get your server to start.

Comment: It helped it seems but now I am having problem with this error: error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient_r.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - when starting app using mysql ...

Comment: `ls /usr/lib/libmysqlclient* -al`. They probably renamed this file, find out what the new name is and create an appropriate symlink. Once you get your server up, I would recommend backing up your data (if you haven't already), then do a clean install of mysql.

Comment: I have find it is in folder /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ as file libmysqlclient.so.18 so what should i do exactly? :)

Comment: Try `ln -s /usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.16 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18` and `ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so.16 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18`.

Answer (score 1):

SUGGESTIONS:

1) Make sure you can start mysql manually:

sudo /etc/rc.d/mysqld start

2) "chkconfig" is one tool you can use to make sure mysqld starts automatically:

http://www.techenclave.com/open-source-linux/ubuntu-server-mysql-does-not-110400/

3) IIRC, the logs should be in `/var/log/messages` (general) and `/var/log/mysql/*.log`

4) And yeah, [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) would probably have been a better place to post this question.  As well as [Linuxquestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/)

Comment: Here are my errors with commands I used http://paste2.org/p/2044417

Answer (score 1):

You have to start mysql on your server.

There should be a startup script in /etc/init.d that you need to run.

You also should have been prompted to enter a root password.

Here are some more hints from the Ubuntu website:

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/mysql.html

Comment: I know hot to start and setup mysql server - if you read well i mentoned that it was working excellent before upgrade now it says these errors: http://paste2.org/p/2044417